# Try to understand a bit more with /etc/hosts

Tags: ubuntu, hosts

**The goal**

Type wiki.me (a park domain) in web browser, will direct to 198.35.26.96 (which is the ip of en.wikipedia.org), then eventually display content in en.wikipedia.org

Using ubuntu 14.10 and I added 
**198.35.26.96 wiki.me wiki** to /etc/hosts. I tested it and it seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **wiki** from **198.35.26.96 wiki.me wiki** and make sure no **#** at this line

Answer (score 0):

> I added 198.35.26.96 wiki.me wiki to /etc/host

You said that [198.35.26.96](http://dig.ua/search/198.35.26.96) (which is the ip of en.wikipedia.org), but it's WIKIMEDIA

> Type wiki.me (a park domain) in web browser, will direct to
>   198.35.26.96 (which is the ip of en.wikipedia.org), then eventually display content in en.wikipedia.org

If you want that when you tap on wiki.me there will be en.wikipedia.org, there are 2 ways:

1. redirect on server, that serve for wiki.me
2. proxy all queries from wiki.me to en.wikipedia.org on server, that serve for wiki.me